# FailedToParse: Database name cannot have reserved characters for mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
FailedToParse: Database name cannot have reserved characters for mongodb:// URL: mongodb+srv://cluster0-lh5ma.mongodb.net/<dbname> try 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongo.exe --help' for more information
```

Unable to find the issue initially, but finally found that issue is due to not inserting database name at end of the path
solution:

```
mongodb:// URL: mongodb+srv://cluster0-lh5ma.mongodb.net/testDB
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace  with the name of the database that connections will use by default.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided might solve

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.cuehp.mongodb.net/**dbname**" --username name

to

mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.cuehp.mongodb.net/**database**" --username name
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace  with your data base name
i.e if your database name is project_One then

mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.mztxj.mongodb.net/" --username your name

replace  with project_One